# segmentation and reassembly for ftp over tcp/ip atmega 8 bit microcontrollers

Tags: c, sockets, ftp, tcp

I have two MCUs: atmega8 with SD card along Node MCU - located at different places.
how do i send a hex file of 1MB size from mcu1 to mcu2 by using node mcu's via tcip/ip protocol ?

edit: I have done socket programming in windows environment !
      Also, I know how to read/write file in SD card, my problem is... where could I refer for segmentation and reassembly of that 1 MB file.

note: segmentation @MCU1 and reassembly @MCU2

Segmentation @ MCU1 : reading the hex file ybte by byte and sending to the other end via ftp over tcp/ip.

Answer (score 0):

TCP maybe not the best choice for Atmega8 because it is too heavy for controllers.

If both MCU under your control you may consider use [TFTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1350) (Trivial FTP) for file transfer. It:

- Based on UDP and UDP is very lightweight protocol
- Supports segmentation and reassembling
- Has retransmissions and delivery guarantee
- Can send more than one packet at time (acknowledge window)
- Is standard

So it has almost all features of TCP but also lightweight and I believe you can easily find free implementation for it.